# How to select a div and delete the selected div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I had like to create an CRUD operation. I can able to create an DIV, Save the content to the Div, I'm unable to delete the DIV. I need to delete the selected DIV which i has created. I stuck how to select the DIV and delete the selected DIV.

```
Note: Should use only plain javaScript only.
```

Problem:

1. Need to delete that highlighted Div.

Please refer my below try code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var addid = 0;
    function createJob() {
        var jobList = document.getElementById("jobList");

        if(document.getElementById('jobitem_' + (addid))) {
            if((document.getElementById('jobitem_' + (addid)).textContent) == "") {

            }else{
                addid++;
                jobNameCreation(jobList,addid); 
            }
        }
        if(addid == 0){
            addid++;
            jobNameCreation(jobList,addid);
        }

    }

    function saveJob() {
        var text_id = 'jobitem_' + addid;
            var mainDiv = document.getElementById(text_id);
        if(mainDiv.children[0].value == ""){
            alert("please enter job name");
        }else{
            mainDiv.textContent =mainDiv.children[0].value; 
        }
    }

    function deleteJob() {
        /*var t = '';
                if(window.getSelection){
            alert("1");
                    t = window.getSelection();
                }else if(document.getSelection){
            alert("2");
                    t = document.getSelection();
                }else if(document.selection){
            alert("3");
                    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
                }
                alert(t);
        */


    }





    function selectText(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
    }

    function jobNameCreation(jobList,addid){
        var text = document.createElement('div');
            text.id = 'jobitem_' + addid;
            text.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='' style='padding:5px; width: 185px;'  />";
        text.onclick = function (e) {
                 selectText(text.id);
        };
        jobList.appendChild(text);  
    }


</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="createJob();"> Create </button>  
    <button type="button" onclick="saveJob();"> Save </button>  
    <button type="button" onclick="deleteJob();"> Delete </button>  
    <br>
    <div id="jobListContainer">
        <div id="jobList">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: do you want to remove one div or all div creted under `jobList` div ?

Comment: Need to remove selected Div Alone, under JobList.. @Yagnesh

Comment: how would you select div ?

Comment: That is the problem in facing, i need to highlight the same to use with blue color. @Yagnesh

Comment: I resolved the highlight problem @Yagnesh. just need to delete the selected one. Just refer my updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is that when your function `selectText(containerid)` is called store your containerid into global variable and based on that id you will remove your selected div in `deleteJob()` function which is call on Delete button click.

```
 var addid = 0;
 var selectedId = '';  
 function selectText(containerid) {
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
    selectedId = containerid;
 }  

 function deleteJob() {
    document.getElementById(selectedId).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the remove() function

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");

elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
// or
elem.remove();
```

Comment: How to get the "myDiv" is the probelm im facing. The selected Div should be highlighted and need to get the reference of it.

Comment: You can highlight your div by adding a class name `div.className="highlightclass"` . To remove your div you have to keep a reference on it or search by a specific id.

Comment: To select your div ( if i understand is your 'jobitem_' + (addid) div ? ) You can keep a temporary reference in you createJob function `var jobItem = document.getElementById('jobitem_' + (addid))`. ( you can also use it in your if statement to avoid research the dom)

Answer (score 0):

Guess what you are looking for is [anchorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.anchorNode)

> **Selection.anchorNode** 
>       Returns the node in which the selection begins. 
>       -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.anchorNode

… and the dynamically created ‘*job'*’ `div`s should be valid for the `anchorNode` to fetch them. So, use the below code to create and delete them — http://jsfiddle.net/uMhXM/2/

```
document.onLoad = function () {
    jobListContainer = document.getElementById('jobListContainer');
    jobList = document.getElementById('jobList');
}
```

```
function createJob() {
    //Create an INPUT to get user input 
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    if (input === undefined || input === null) {
        input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.id = 'input';
    }
    //Add the created INPUT to 'jobListContainer'
    jobListContainer.appendChild(input);
}
```

```
function saveJob() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    if (input !== undefined && input !== null) {
        if (input.value !== "") {
            //Create the 'job' DIV enclosing INPUT value
            var job = document.createElement('div');
            job.setAttribute("id", "job_" +jobList.children.length);
            job.textContent=input.value
            //Add the created 'job' DIV to 'jobList'
            jobList.appendChild(job);
            //Remove the INPUT
            input.remove();

        } else {
            alert("Please Enter Job");
        }
    }
}
```

```
function deleteJob(){
    window.getSelection().anchorNode.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It remove's all Div inside jobList.

Comment: were the 'div's inside _jobList_ created correctly? i.e all the tags were closed? Post a working fiddle of what you got so far if possible so that I can make the changes in your code directly

Comment: im unable to post the code jsfiddle. Its giving error. so only i posted the entire code here. The above is the full code. Even i tried to edit your jsfiddle code with my code, getting same error.

Comment: Hey there, The issue is also in your code for creation, the `DIV`s that were dynamically created were not valid it seems, Hence the `anchorNode` didn't pick them up! I have added the edited code and a working fiddle to my answer. Hope that helps.